# Random whitespace in Google Chrome extension

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, fieldset

I have some CSS:

```
fieldset {
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0em;
}
legend {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
}
#myform{
    width: 330px;
    margin: 0em;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

When I embed it with `<style>`, it works perfectly fine:

[image: The extension with embedded CSS]

But when I put the same CSS into a stylesheet and import it using `<link>`, I get some random whitespace:

[image: The extension with the same CSS, but imported from an external stylesheet with <link>]

I have removed the form elements completely, and there is still whitespace (although if I keep them in, there is considerably more of it). I used the Chrome developers console to check form and body height using `$(body).css("height")` (and the same for the form), and it gives me a number which is way too small to include the whitespace, but seems to match the height if the whitespace is ignored. Where is this coming from?

Comment: Are you injecting the html to another website?

Comment: can you share screen while you inspecting the element.

Comment: There are zillion reasons why this could be happening. Can't really debug something without access to the full page. 

Can you post a link to the page itself or paste the html with relevant css and js?

Comment: The thing is, I removed all HTML apart from my `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`, which can be evidently seen above. Do you want a screenshot of what the console is telling me about the styles?

Comment: Unless I interpreted your code wrong, your CSS combined with a stripped down fieldset/legend does NOT render your screenshot. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MXWqN/

Comment: I've tried to replicated bug you are describing but no luck (Linux / Chrome 23), check my minimal example: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8989748/MyStuffExt.zip .

Comment: is the `<link>` tag inside the form or in the `<head>` element of the html ?

Comment: I think `!important` doesn't work in extensions :o

Comment: @Bluefire, that's not true `!important` works in external stylesheet too. 

My suggestion is weird but you may give it a try. 

Give a space between the selector and the curly brace in your CSS. 
`#myform {
    width: 330px;
    margin: 0em;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug, when changing the margin of the body back and forth in the developers console it gets right again. Setting this property in the CSS doesn't have any effect at all.

A measly workaround would be creating a javascript file for your popup, like `popup.js`, and then change the margin in there after the popup window is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.body.style.margin = '8px';
});
```

I took `8px` as value because that's the standard value of a Chrome popup:

[image]

You should consider reporting this bug to the [Chrome issues list](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

put CSS with !important keyword
i.e.

```
#myform{
    width: 330px !important;
    margin: 0em !important;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work D: I tried adding `!important` to all properties, and the whitespace is still there.